# How to solve Android TV emulator DNS lookup error? (java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host)

Tags: android

On my Android TV 6.0 emulator, my code got the following error when making HTTP requests (e.g. http://www.example.com/):

`java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.example.com": No address associated with hostname`

But no problem if I replace domain name with IP address: `http://93.184.216.34/`.

Also `adb shell ping` shows the following result:

```
$ adb shell ping www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com

$ adb shell ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=127 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=128 ms
```

So far I tried:

- Making sure I have the right permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
- Try higher version (Android TV 7.0) emulator (Didn't work).
- Try `adb shell setprop net.dns1 8.8.8.8` and other DNS servers (Didn't work).
- Under adb shell: `ndc resolver setnetdns eth0 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4` (Didn't work).
- Run my app on a phone emulator (Android 6.0) (Worked, so I guess my code has no problem).

Comment: Do other apps on that emulator seem to have similar problems?

Comment: @CommonsWare Tried Account settings on emulator, adding Google account also failed, showing "Internet connection lost" error.

Comment: All of this points to a problem specific to the emulator images for Android TV. I do not know what you can do about that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to latest Emulator and SDK tools and the problem disappeared.